# What is the priority of rules in layout spec w/r width and height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Using RelativeLayouts, I have a layout that is

```
layout_alignParentLeft="true"
layout_alignParentRight="true"
layout_below="id/----"
layout_above="id/++++"
width="fill_parent"
```

What height should I set ?

I am tempted to use `fill_parent` but the view is smaller than the parent in height.

If I use `wrap_content`, I will have problems later because I use the width of the view in my calculations

I am looking for something like this (look at the stars) :

```
---------------
***************
***************
***************
***************
+++++++++++++++
```

Comment: you sould use match_parent for the height, and having no problems, because you're using the below and above parameters. You can make sure it works by setting ---- alignParentTop and ++++++ alginParentbottom

Comment: FILL_PARENT is deprecated, you should use MATCH_PARENT (doesnt really do anything, but might cause errors in the future)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this  for a map layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"       
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_status_lights"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@color/Red"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"        
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

    </LinearLayout>           


     <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView       
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_status_lights"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_data"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        
        android:id="@+id/mapa_destino" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_data"
        android:layout_widt="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/Red"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="6dp"                      
        ">

     </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and it is like this :

[image]